# Correct Way to Nest MySQLi in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a question which is probably fairly basic to answer with regards to nesting a MySQLi query within another query. I'm not sure if this is best practice and would appreciate if someone could help by letting me know if the example below works well, or if there is a better way of doing it.

Table 1: students

```
id | linked_teacher | student_name | student_age
1  | 1              | Bob Eaves    | 15 
2  | 1              | Ellen Robs   | 11
3  | 2              | Will Tops    | 7
4  | 3              | Scott Long   | 13
```

Table 2: Teachers

```
id | teacher_name
1  | Mrs Green
2  | Mr Wood
3  | Dr Grey
4  | Professor Long
```

My PHP then looks like below, currently:

```
$sql = "SELECT linked_teacher, student_name, student_age FROM students";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $linked_teacher = $row["linked_teacher"];

    $sql2 = "SELECT teacher_name FROM teachers WHERE teacher_name = $linked_teacher";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($result2->num_row > 0) {
      while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $teacher_name = $row2["teacher_name"];
      }
    }

    echo "$row["teacher_name"]. " - ". $row["student_name"]. " - " . $row["student_age"]";
  }
}
```

This would output the following:

```
Mrs Green - Bob Eaves - 15
Mrs Green - Ellen Robs - 11
Mr Wood - Will Tops - 7
Dr Grey - Scott Long - 13
```

Now whilst I appreciate my example doesn't really need two tables, if I can understand the correct way of answering this example, which I am sure I have not done in my solution, then I can apply the theory to more complex solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to learn how to use `JOIN`. This should be covered in any beginning book or tutorial on SQL.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: This is an *N+1* query situation where, as Bill says, you can avoid this by pre-fetching using a `LEFT JOIN`. I think you've got a potential problem here since you're using the teacher's name as a foreign key. Those aren't sufficiently unique and can change, causing mis-linked data. It's much better to use a fixed identifier like teacher employee ID or some self-generated number.

Answer (score 0):

Use one loop and join the tables. Your code is faster (comment 3) and simpler. Definitely follow up and learn about dealing with tainted data as the second comment above points out. Good luck!

```
 $sql = "SELECT teacher_name, student_name, student_age FROM students JOIN teachers ON linked_teacher = teachers.id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "$row["teacher_name"]. " - ". $row["student_name"]. " - " . $row["student_age"]";
  }
}
```